# question about compiled program usage of external libraries

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I know this might be a very stupid question but I am new to compiled languages (my domain is mostly scripting languages like PHP, Python or JavaScript).

I am learning C++ for one project where it is the only language I can use.

I wrote a program in Ubuntu 10.10 and then compiled it. I can run the generated binary file from cmd like this and it works:

```
sudo ./compiled-program
```

But, I have used some external libraries in the program (OpenCV). Does that mean that all computers where I will run the program will have to have OpenCV installed? Or is OpenCV bundled inside the compiled binary file? Will it work on PCs without OpenCV installed?

Comment: edited out your apology for being a stupid question because its not. :)

Comment: This is emphatically not a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read a few things about [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29), and particularly what makes the difference between static and dynamic libraries. To quote the basic definitions so you get the point :

> A static library, also known as an
>   archive, consists of a set of routines
>   **which are copied into a target
>   application by the compiler, linker,
>   or binder**, producing object files and
>   a stand-alone executable file.
>
> [...]
>
> Dynamic linking involves loading the
>   subroutines of a library (which may be
>   referred to as a DLL, especially under
>   Windows, or as a DSO (dynamic shared
>   object) under Unix-like systems) into
>   an application program **at load time or
>   runtime, rather than linking them in
>   at compile time**.

Answer (score 2):

Not a stupid question at all!

The "normal" way this works - is that your program has been linked against a "Shared Library" - in which case, yes, the user needs the OpenCV (or whatever bundle includes the shared library) to work.

If you compiled as a *static* executable, (using the -static) flag, then it, and *all* libraries would be included directly into your executable, making a bit of a larger executable that wastes more memory, because it isn't using a *shared* library.

There are ways that you could compile your program to link *only* your OpenCV libraries as static - but that only can be done if the bundle included a static library ".a" vs. a shared one ".so".

Answer (score 2):

If you had to build your code against dependencies, like OpenCV, it depends on if you did static or dynamic linking.

See here which has sections covering these ideas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)

For starters, try doing this on the command line:

`ldd compiled-program`

You will get output like this (as an example, I did `ldd` on my `python` binary in `/usr/bin`):

```
birryree@lilun:/usr/bin$ ldd python
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7ff7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7fd5000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7fd1000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/i686/cmov/libutil.so.1 (0xb7fcd000)
        libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0xb7f82000)
        libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0xb7e2a000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7e16000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xb7df0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7caa000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80000000)
```

Python wants a lot of additional stuff, like `libssl` (part of OpenSSL), the GNU C library (`libc`), and some others.

Now if you're going to be moving this thing around to other systems, you either hope they have an environment similar to yours, distribute it as source and use something like the `autotools`/GNU Build System to build it, or you can forego all that and statically link everything into your binary, which will bring in all the stuff your executable needs without need for a dynamic link.

Answer (score 1):

If you've "compiled against" OpenCV, then machines running your app need it too.  You need to copy the libs when you install your app, or ensure that they're already installed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on wether you are compiling against a shared (Dynamic) library or compiling it into your executable (compiling against a static library).  If you are compiling against a shared library you need to distribute the shared library ... otherwise .. you don't.

Comment: I just added three headers in the cpp file like for example: #include <opencv/highgui.h> and then used OpenCV functions inside the cpp file. Does that mean I used dynamic or static library?

Comment: It means neither ... the choice of static or dynamic comes down to the linker not the compiler.

Comment: That's not good. I have no idea what linker was used, I compile in Anjuta IDE by clicking the Compile button.

Comment: @Richard:  Then you need to do a bit of research into your platform.  Otherwise the answer to your question is ENTIRELY arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of libraries, static and dynamically loaded.
Statically loaded libraries are joined with your binary file, while dynamically loaded libraries are loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not the executable is [statically-built](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build) or [dynamically linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computer_science%29#Dynamic_linking). In a statically-built executable it is the case that the library files the executable needs are compiled into the executable and there isn't an need to carry around additional library files. In a dynamically linked executable it is the case that the library files the executable needs are linked at runtime and therefore a copy of the library files are needed at runtime.